# How integrity level of a process is determined?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, process

I want to launch a process with high integrity level. The parent process is running as a System service, LocalSystem account. In one Windows 2008 machine, the sub process is of high level while in another 2008 machine, the process is the "medium" level. It looks like `CreateProcessAsUser` get different level in different machine.

```
if (!WTSQueryUserToken(sessionID, &hToken)) 
{//The admin user logged in the rdp session of "sessionID".
    return;
}
BOOL fSuccess = CreateProcessAsUser(hToken, NULL, cmdLine, NULL, NULL,
TRUE,CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE,NULL, workDir, &si, &pi);
```

What bring about the difference? Is there a config or program way to solve it?

Comment: Perhaps one of those machines has UAC disabled, so the administrator doesn't get a split token?  Or perhaps in one case the account in question is the built in Administrator account, which is (by default) exempt from getting a split token?

Answer (score 1):

Don't count on the ACL of a user. Sure, it's likely that a LocalSystem account contains a High Integrity Level ACL, but that's not the reliable way to get that IL ACL. The high IL SID is well-known (`SID: S-1-16-12288`). Put it in a security descriptor, and pass that to CreateProcess.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to change the integrity level of the retrieved token before launching the new process by calling [SetTokenInformation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379591%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with the `TOKEN_INFORMATION_CLASS` parameter set to `TokenIntegrityLevel`.